# \bibhyperref undefined?

Tags: biblatex, errors, hyperref

I'm trying to use the macro `\bibhyperref` to link to the bibliography. I'm citing the Bible in footnotes and rather than comb through the list of citation styles I think it is easier to write my own macros that do basically the same thing. (I am fine with the MLA citation style for all my other non-Bible citations.) It's weird because I'm doing the Bible citations sometimes as footnotes (in one section of the document) and sometimes inline (everywhere else).

I had no trouble writing a pair of macros, one for inline and the other for footnote. The only problem is, **even though `\bibhyperref[key]{text}` is in the bibLaTeX appears to be still current in the package documentation and I even included `hyperref=true` in the package options, LaTeX reports that `\bibhyperref` is not a defined control sequence.** I know I could just look in the package source and copy the definition of the macro into my own document, but if there's a less convoluted solution I'd like to know what it is. Is there something I'm missing? I'm using LuaLaTeX, if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\bibhyperref` is only defined in places where the concept of an entrykey makes sense. So for example if you define your own citation command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\testcite}
   {}{\bibhyperref{hallo}}{}{}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\testcite{doody}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ok thank you so much!